# how to get a wordpress blog page to show differnt nav bar from maine page

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi im a web dev an im trying to get word press to use a 2nd navigation for my blog section. i have the main site all set up but what i want is when i hit the blog in my top nav to show a differnt navigation for the blog section. i have tried using the following code in the header.php

```
<?php
 if (is_single('blog')){
 wp_nav_menu(array('menu'=>'secondary' ));
 }
 ?>
```

but this code does not seem to work even though the theme supports 2 navigations.

```
 <nav class="Seo-nav">
 <div class="Seo-nav-inner">
 <?php
echo theme_get_menu(array(
        'source' => theme_get_option('theme_menu_source'),
        'depth' => theme_get_option('theme_menu_depth'),
        'menu' => 'primary-menu',
        'class' => 'Seo-hmenu'
    )
);

get_sidebar('nav');
?>
```

the above code is the code i use to call my navigation. is there any way to get a specific page or pages to show the one menu? any help on this would be great. never had to make certain pages have different navigation before so this is a new one on me.

Comment: Read this: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/possible-to-have-different-navigation-bar-on-each-page

Comment: unfortunately thats not what im trying to do the issuse is that i want my main nav to change to a differnt nav on other pages

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go here two ways.

One is to only show children of current page on the second like

```
function show_different_nav(){
  global $post;
  $sec_nav=wp_list_pages("child_of=".$post->ID);
 return $sec_nav;
 }
```

now call show_different_nav() in your template.

The other way would be to write an own filter. I modified the http://wordpress.org/plugins/get-different-menus/ in this case.

```
 add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'get_different_custom_menu_item_according_to_page_slug', 10, 2 );

function get_different_custom_menu_item_according_to_page_slug ( $items, $args ) {
$current_id=(int)$GLOBALS['post']->ID;
    $current_slug=$GLOBALS['post']->slug;


$the_nmo = wp_get_nav_menu_object($current_slug); 

if ($the_nmo==""){}else{

$menu_id=$the_nmo->term_id;
$items_2 = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu_id);
$items="";


if ($args->theme_location == 'secondary') {

    foreach ($items_2 as $item){

    $link_page_id = (int)($item->object_id);


if ($current_id == $link_page_id){$cur=" current-menu-item current_page_item";}else{$cur="";
} 

    $items .= '<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page'.$cur.'"><a  href="'.$item->url.'">'.$item->title.'</a></li>';

    }
    }

}
return $items;
}
```

In my opinion you need a menu for this called exactly the same as the page slug.

Answer (score 0):

Like was said in comments earlier, you'll need Conditional Tags. Probably for you specifically, the [`is_page()` conditional](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_PAGE_Page).

```
<?php
if (is_page('blog')) {
   // Echo this menu on the blog slug page
      wp_nav_menu(array(
          'theme_location' => '[name_of_menu]'
      ));

} else {
  // Otherwise, echo this one
      wp_nav_menu(array(
          'theme_location' => '[name_of_main_menu]'
      ));
}
```

See [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) for the wp_nav_menu attributes. Can print out the menu other ways, that's just the one I recommend.

Depending how you blog is set up, `is_page('blog')` may need to be `is_home()`,  `'blog' == get_post_type()`, or some other variation.